# vuelidate: submit button is disabled even when an element is not required

Tags: vuetify.js, vuelidate

I am doing form validation. Here is my code:

```
<v-menu ref="menu3" :close-on-content-click="false" v-model="anniversaryVisibility" :nudge-right="10" :return-value.sync="enquiryForm.anniversary"
   lazy
   transition="scale-transition"
   offset-y
   full-width
   min-width="290px">

   <v-text-field 
        slot="activator" 
        v-model="enquiryForm.anniversary" 
        label="Anniversary" 
        append-icon="event" 
        outline 
        readonly
        :error-messages="fieldErrors('enquiryForm.anniversary')"
        @input="$v.enquiryForm.anniversary.$touch()"
        @blur="$v.enquiryForm.anniversary.$touch()"
        ></v-text-field>

        <v-date-picker v-model="enquiryForm.anniversary" @input="$refs.menu3.save(enquiryForm.anniversary)"></v-date-picker>
 </v-menu>
```

Here is my submit button:

```
<v-btn flat lg color="secondary" @click="submit" :disabled="$v.$invalid">Submit</v-btn>
```

Here is my script:

```
const defaultFormData = {
anniversary: ''
}

validations: {
    enquiryForm: {
        anniversary: { }
    }
}
```

Anniversary date is not required in my form. Yet I must pick anniversary date to enable the submit button. The submit button remains disabled until the anniversary date is picked. Anyone have any ideas to submit the form.

This is my submit code:

```
submit ( ) {
        this.$store.dispatch('addEnquiry', {
            date: moment().format(),
            customername: this.enquiryForm.customername,
            contactnumber: this.enquiryForm.contactnumber,
            alternatecontactnumber: this.enquiryForm.alternatecontactnumber,
            emailid: this.enquiryForm.emailid,
            address: this.enquiryForm.address,
            dateofbirth: this.enquiryForm.dateofbirth,
            anniversary: this.enquiryForm.anniversary,
            requirement: this.enquiryForm.requirement,
            preferences: this.enquiryForm.preferences,
            informationSource: this.enquiryForm.informationSource,
            investmentRange: this.enquiryForm.investmentRange,
            preferredBank: this.enquiryForm.preferredBank,
            loan: this.enquiryForm.loan,
            owncontribution: this.enquiryForm.owncontribution,
            sourceofinformation:this.enquiryForm.sourceofinformation,
            projectId: this.enquiryForm.projectId,
            company: this.enquiryForm.company,
            designation: this.enquiryForm.designation,
            executiveId: this.enquiryForm.executiveId
        })
        .then( ( result ) => {
            this.close();
        } )
        .catch( ( err ) => {
            console.log( err );
        } )
    }
```

Comment: Can we use validations: {enquiryForm: {anniversary: { not(required)}}}